# Rails 3 AJAX Follow Button Different Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a Rails 3 app with a follow/unfollow button.

The forms `_follow.html.erb` and `_unfollow.html.erb` are in controller `A`. Controller `B` has the actual create and destroy methods (it's the center of the `has_many :through` relationship). Therefore, the `create.js.erb` and `destroy.js.erb` associated with the follow and unfollow are located in controller `B`'s view folder.

The AJAX code looks like this:
`$("#followform").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'A/follow') %>")`

The code works when I replace `render A/follow` with something like `<p>Testing</p>`, but fails to render the partial with the code above.

Is it not possible to render views from foreign controllers in this way? I checked the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) and they seem to suggest that it is. So, does anyone know the problem here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Check your JS error console and see if your getting a bad response. ("Network" in Chrome is awesome. I hear Firebug has a net monitor, too)

Comment: Yup, it says "Internal Server Error 500" in there right after I click the button, which seems to suggest that it can't find that partial. But, if it's there (and the button's function works properly), why would this be happening?

Comment: Which console did you use? If you click the response in Chrome, then click preview tab, you can see the actual error.

Comment: Hmm. When unfollowing it says `Called id for nil...` and when following it says `undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class`. But the button still works, because when I refresh the page, it shows correctly, as if I followed or unfollowed successfully. So, what are these two errors referencing?

Comment: Want to throw the error and some code up or into a pastebin and I'll take a look?

Comment: Plus the `params` you're sending

Comment: Here are the two form partials `_follow.html.erb` and `_unfollow.html.erb`: http://pastebin.com/4fA2SW6u

Comment: The errors are as mentioned above and reference the form lines that I have in the pastebin above. And thanks again for any help!

Comment: Have you tried renaming the js files to _create.js.erb and _destroy.js.erb respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is your partials aren't getting all the information they need, as in you have an instance variable in the partial that isn't set, or a local variable perhaps.

Check all the variables that are in your partial and make sure they're being set somewhere up the chain.

If you post your actual controller action that serves up the partial, and the partial code itself, we can probably help more.